# Is there any customised library to generate entities equivalent to mysql tables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I want to generate entities out of mysql schema using sequlize library. I found ways to generate in javascript but couldn't find any to generate typescript entities(Relations should be included).
 Can anyone please point me to typescript sequlize or customized library which can do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweaked the sequilize-auto library to generate mysql entities in Typescript with relations, it may be helpful to you
https://github.com/realvariabledas/sequelize-auto